# PHP: Getting the url's value which is not parameter

Tags: php, url, get

As I know the only way to get a value from the url is to use the `$_GET[];` . To do this the url must be of the format: `http://domain.com/index.php?var1=value1`
And then to do the following:

```
<?php
$value1 = $_GET['var1'];
echo($value1);
?>
```

What I really want is to get the value of the url in the format:

```
http://domain.com/value1
```

I know that is not a really php job, but while my index is index.php can I get the value1 from the url? Using something different rather than HTTP Get method.
Cheers.

[SOLUTION]:

I use the URL rewriting to make it work as @KevBot suggest. So what I did:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?value=$1 [L]
```

Comment: the url will be in various $_SERVER variables

Comment: you mean that the `domain.com/value` can be parsed using a $_SERVER variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called URL rewriting. You need to modify .htaccess.

[Here's a great tutorial:](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/)

Comment: .htaccess does not have to be in the root folder

Comment: @Dagon, that is correct, I have modified my answer.

Comment: yea I need to implement this in a subdirectory. 
Gyus, while the url will be a variable url and not constant I have to use regular expression?

Comment: it depends upon how strict you want it to be. I would recommend it as you don't want multiple URL's for the same content.

Comment: Yea in the exmaple:
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   horses.htm   Xu8JuefAtua.htm`
horses.htm is constant I need a way that works for any. For instance, a rule that get the value of the `http://domain.com/something` where something is not a constant and parse it into `index.php?var=something` it is possible?

Comment: @ProgrJohn awesome! I'm glad you were able to get it figured.